# Swapping values between two vectors so that sum of max_elements of two vectors is minimum

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a question from Codechef but please bear with me.
https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO16001

The contest is for the preparation of the Zonal Computing Olympiad held in India, so its not a competitive contest from which I'd earn something as such. Just need a little help to see what is wrong with my code, because I have a feeling I've overlooked something big and stupid. :P

So basically the question is summed up as this.

> Lets say that there are two vectors or arrays. You need to swap
>   elements between them such that the sum of their maximum elements
>   is minimum. However you can swap at most K times. Then output 
>   the value of this sum.

My approach was simple. Take the highest number from Vector1 (V1) and swap it with the lowest from V2. Add the highest values of each. Do the same, but this time swap the highest number from V2 with the lowest from V1. Add the highest values of each. The better swapping will be the one with the lowest sum and continue from there K times.

So for example:

V1 = 5 6 7 9

V2 = 9 10 5 4

In this case, if K = 1
I would first swap V1's 9 with V2's 4. This gives:

V1 = 5 6 7 4

V2 = 9 10 5 9

Sum of highest number as 17, as compared to earlier's 19. The second swap I could do is 10 from V2 with 5 from V1 giving:

V1 = 10 6 7 4

V2 = 9 5 5 9

This gives sum as 19, so better was the first swap and the output should be 17.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define print(vec) for (int i  = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) { cout << vec[i] << " "; } cout << endl;
using namespace std;

vector <long long int> s1, s2;

inline long long int calc(vector <long long int> v1, vector<long long int> v2) {
    return *max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end()) + *max_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
}
int main(){


    long long int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    long long int x;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        s1.push_back(x);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        s2.push_back(x);
    }
    while (k--) {

        vector <long long int> b1(s1);
        vector <long long int> b2(s2);
        long long int skewb = calc(b1,b2);

        vector <long long int> v1(s1);
        vector <long long int> v2(s2);

        auto mn1 = minmax_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        auto mn2 = minmax_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());

        iter_swap(mn1.second, mn2.first);

        b1 = vector <long long int> (v1);
        b2 = vector <long long int> (v2);
        skewb = calc(v1,v2);

        v1 = vector <long long int> (s1);
        v2 = vector <long long int> (s2);
        mn1 = minmax_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        mn2 = minmax_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());

        iter_swap(mn2.second, mn1.first);
        if (calc(v1,v2) <= skewb) {
            b1 = vector <long long int> (v1);
            b2 = vector <long long int> (v2);
        }

        if (b1 == s1 && b2 == s2) cout << "LOL" << endl;
        s1 = vector <long long int> (b1);
        s2 = vector <long long int> (b2);
    }



    cout << calc(s1, s2) << endl;
}
```

Please note that this does all swaps i.e K. So even if the current arrangement was the best, it would still swap some values. Earlier I was breaking when the current arrangement was the best. The reason for doing this is because I was getting all test cases right except TWO! And guess what was even more annoying, one was from each task! :( 
So I realised it must be necessary to complete all K switches. However even now I am getting 2 testcases wrong, there must be something I have overlooked.

Any idea what it is?
Link to solution: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/11574501

And btw, Task 1 has K = 1.

Comment: @tobi303, if you read the statement on codechef, you will understand everything.

Comment: Sorry I meant max_element and element instead of lengths. I was referring to the link to the Codechef problem I included.

Comment: @AlexStone, Please update the question details. And intuition why your algorithm is correct?

Comment: Could you tell me which test cases(Task #) of yours are failing on codechef judge.

Comment: @AlexStone I provided my implementation which got accepted. But I suggest you code it yourself after reading the explanation.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Yeah okay thanks! Are you tempux btw? :p

Comment: @AlexStone Yes. I pointed out the problem with your code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you change the arrays between swaps and therefore there is the possibility of swapping one item back and forth between arrays. I mean in the first swap you place element *x* from array1 to array2 and in the next swap it is possible that you swap it back again.

Also you do a lot of vector copying which make the code inefficient. Even if the logic of your code was correct your code wouldn't have passed the time limit because your approach is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

---

First note that optimal answer is when all the elements in one array are bigger than all the elements in the other array.

- Sort both arrays
- for  *x*  from 0 to *k*

  - hypothetically swap *x* minimum elements of first array with *x* maximum elements of the second array.
  - result = min(result, max(result, max(first array) + max(second array) )
  - hypothetically swap *x* maximum elements of first array with *x* minimum elements of the second array.
  - result = min(result, max(result, max(first array) + max(second array) )
- *result* will hold the final answer

Since both arrays are sorted you can find maximum elements of the arrays after hypothetical swap with one comparison.

```
V1 = 5 6 7 9 -> 5 6 7 9
V2 = 9 10 5 4 -> 4 5 9 10

x = 0   no swaps: result = V1[size-1] + V2[size-1]
x = 1 
        result = max(V1[size-1], V2[size-1]) + max(V1[0], V2[size-2])
        result = max(V1[size-2], V2[0]) + max(V1[size-1],V2[size-1])
x = 2 
        result = max(V1[size-1], V2[size-1]) + max(V1[1], V2[size-3])
        result = max(V1[size-3], V2[1]) + max(V1[size-1],V2[size-1])
...
```

This is the accepted implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;

    vector<int> v[2];
    for ( int i=0;i < 2;++i ){
        for ( int j=0;j<n;++j ){
            int temp; cin>> temp;
            v[i].push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    sort(v[0].begin(),v[0].end());
    sort(v[1].begin(),v[1].end());

    int result = v[0].back() + v[1].back();

    for ( int i=1; i<=k; ++i ){
        int t = max(v[0][n-1],v[1][n-1]) + max(v[0][i-1],v[1][n-1-i]);
        result = min(result,t);
        t = max(v[0][n-1-i],v[1][i-1]) + max(v[0][n-1],v[1][n-1]);
        result = min(result,t);
    }

    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: why max(first array) - max(second array) ? we want the sum of tallest books to be minimum.

Comment: @dd2 Provide an input which this algorithm won't work on it.

Comment: If I would have known, it would be corrected by now. Please try your solution on codechef and you will realize that there are some corner cases. btw some peoples have solved this question already.

Comment: @dd2 So you don't know what is wrong with the code and downvoted it 1 minute after I post the answer. Ironically I submitted my implemenation and it got accepted.

Comment: @AlexStone Yes, it did.

Comment: Not sure about inefficiency because all the other accepted test cases ran in max 0.06 seconds, but yeah I saw yours was 0.0 seconds.

Comment: But I don't really change the vectors in between swaps. I copy the best one to b1 and b2 without changing the original ones till the end. :/ Do you have any idea of a possible test case that won't work for my implementation?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your full source code so I can test it.

Comment: This is the full source code, just replace void solveBookshelves() with int main()

Comment: `5 5 3 5 2 7 1 14 2 3 10 4` use this input. The correct answer is 17. Your code gives 18. Simulate your code and you will get my point.

Comment: Any with K = 1, though? :p

Comment: `K=1` has no problem. The problem is with bigger K when you swap items back and forth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124053/discussion-between-alex-stone-and-sudomakeinstall2).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to minimize  the sum of the two maximum elements, one from each array.You can do only K swaps.

Let's assume arrays are sorted (this will not change the algorithm). 
Choose the array where the k element in order is smaller. Let's call this array S and the other array B.
In each swap take the biggest element from array S and swap with the smallest in array B.
If at some time all elements in array S are smaller then in B stop.

Explanation: We know that the maximum element from both array will be in the solution.So we want the other array have the smallest possible maximum element.
This is what this algorithm does.

Comment: c'mon, man. Alex has done that same exact thing with one extra check you missed and It is not correct according to codechef judge. I too implemented my own solution, but it did not make it. I believe we might be missing any corner case.

Comment: Yes ugh. There is one really weird case that is somehow missing me. I have tried so many test cases but they all worked.

Comment: Read my solution again , it's not the same as Alex. Down voting me was not fair

Answer (score -1):

The logic of this question is 
For K=1 the lowest skew would be  largest value (suppose found in V1) +  second largest value of the other vector(called V2)

I have given way below how to do it

For K=1 you swap for ones ,now you get two new vectors and you again calulate for K=1 ,that means if you know how to get minimum skew for k=1 ,you can repeat same steps for k times ,so below i have given the steps to find minimum skew --->

There are two vectors V1 and V2

Step 1 --> find the largest element of all ,suppose its in V1

Step 2 --> find the second largest element of the other vector i.e. in this case (second largest element of V2) suppose its name is e2

Step 3 -->find the largest of V2 suppose its name is e1

Step 4 --> swap largest of V2 i.e e1 with a element of V1 (where the element of V1 is less then e2)

Above steps are for k=1 
if you repeat these steps you can have lowest skew

E.g. given in question -->

V1 --> 1 14 2 3 10 4

V2---> 5 1  3 5 2  7

find largest of all--> its 14 in V1

cause largest element is in V1 so find second largest of V2 --> Its 5

find largest of V2 ---> its 7

Swap 7 of V2 with 3 of V1 (Its less then 5)

Calculate skew

Repeat the steps

Comment: Essentially, you're doing what I am doing, but using up computational time of finding the second largest element of the other vector, which you are doing nothing with.

Comment: @ALexStone we have to find second largest element of the other vector so that largest can be replaced with the value less then second largest element, Its sheer mathematical and aptitude logic, so as to get lowest skew

Comment: I don't think this will work. I tried a similar solution before this. And I didn't down vote you.

Comment: @AlexStone okay so basic logic is for K=1 the lowest skew will be the largest value of all + second largest value of the other vector  ,now you will repeat it , i have just given the way to do this