# How would I go about analyzing this algorithm using "Big Oh" notation and how could I improve the run time of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

The algorithm is explained by:

1. if n is even: return 1 + g(n/2).
2. if n is odd: return 1 + g(n-1).
3. if n = 1: return 1.

Code:

```
public static int g(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else if (n%2==0)
        return 1 + g(n/2);
    else
        return 1 + g(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a number is even the right most bit in its binary representation is `0`. Dividing a number by 2 removes this zero.

```
N = 16       => 8       => 4      => 2     => 1
    (10000)2 => (1000)2 => (100)2 => (10)2 => 1
```

When a number is odd the right most bit in its binary representation is `1`. The algorithm decerements the number when it receives an odd number. Decrementing an odd number will result in changing the rightmost bit from `1` to `0`. So the number becomes even and the algorithm then divides this number by 2 so the right most bit will be removed.

So the worst case of the algorithm happens when binary representation of the number is consist of all `1`s:

```
1111111111111
```

When this happens what the algorithm does is remove each 1 in two steps

```
1111111111111 decrement it because it is odd
1111111111110 divide it by two because it even 
111111111111
```

So in the worst case it takes 2* *number of 1s* to reach to `1`. The *number of 1s* is proportionate to log<sub>2</sub>N. So the algorithm belongs to *O(logN)*.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Same reason [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660537/swapping-values-between-two-vectors-so-that-sum-of-max-elements-of-two-vectors-i/39661692#39661692), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673898/divide-array-into-k-contiguos-partitions-such-that-sum-of-maximum-partition-is-m/39675098#39675098) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773052/longest-path-in-a-undirected-and-unweighted-tree-in-python/39773240#39773240) got downvoted :)

Comment: have you checked your stats? I got a serial downvote last week. I flagged it, and the vote was reversed and the user deleted! At least for that one, you got my UV.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think it is a serial downvote, it is more like downvoting competing answers, and I really don't wanna bother the moderators for 4 downvotes. After all 1 downvote is not enough to make the readers completely ignore my answers. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: in this case, why the other answer doesn't get downvoted too then? and yours is better explained.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually I think this other answerer is downvoting my competing answers. Like the other posts that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**complexity : log (n)**

Explanation:

If you look at the binary notation of n and g(n).

```
*****0 => ***** (left shift)
*****1 => ****0 (change last 1 to 0) => **** (left shift)
```

So, it reduces one bit per 2 iterations in the worst case running time.

So total number of operations: **2*log<sub>2</sub>(n)** = **O( log<sub>2</sub>(n) )**  .

Answer (score 0):

`O(lg(n))`: If the input is a power of 2, every call divides by 2, which is obviously `lg(n)`. For any other input, at least every second operation divides by 2 (if one operation subtracts one, the input was off before and is now even). So there are at most `2*log(n)` operations, which is `O(lg(n))`.